# Error trying to use Redux action dispatcher in React component?

Tags: reactjs, redux

Ive created a Rexux store. In my entry point I can add an item to my store and see that it works:

```
    import React from 'react';
    import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
    import { createStore } from 'redux';
    import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
    import allReducers from './reducers';
    import { ADD_TODO_ITEM } from './actionCreators';

    import App from './components/containers/App';

    let store = createStore(allReducers);


    store.subscribe(() => console.log(store.getState()));
    store.dispatch(ADD_TODO_ITEM('test 1'));

    ReactDOM.render(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
      </Provider>,
      document.getElementById('root'),
    );
```

Im trying to use this action dispatcher in my component. When I submit the form below I get the error:

TypeError: dispatch is not a function

I think Im not passing dispatch to AddTodo, but how do you pass dispatch to component?

```
    import React from 'react';
    import { ADD_TODO_ITEM } from '../../actionCreators';

    const AddTodo = ({ dispatch }) => {
      let input;
      return (
        <form
          onSubmit={e => {
            e.preventDefault();
            const text = input.value;
            console.log(text);
            dispatch(ADD_TODO_ITEM(text));
          }}
        >
          <input
            type="text"
            ref={node => {
              input = node;
            }}
          />
          <button type="submit">Add Item</button>
        </form>
      );
    };

    export default AddTodo;
```

Comment: You don't have to pass dispatch.  Since you have wrapped your component with Provider, 'dispatch' can be accessed via props.  So try using 'this.props.dispatch'

Comment: My props is just and empty object.

Comment: Sorry @JayabalajiJ but what do you mean? With the react dev tools I can see that the AddTodo component doesn't have any props.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, `this.props` is empty because you haven't passed any props or connected your component to your redux state. In order to have dispatch in your component, you'll need to use `connect` from [react-redux](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux) which takes 2 arguments, one being `mapStateToProps` and other is `mapDispatchToProps`. The code goes something like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import { ADD_TODO_ITEM } from '../../actionCreators';

const AddTodo = ({ addItem }) => {
    let input;
    return (
        <form
          onSubmit={e => {
          e.preventDefault();
          const text = input.value;
          console.log(text);
          dispatch(addItem(text));
          }}
        >
          <input
            type="text"
            ref={node => {
              input = node;
            }}
          />
          <button type="submit">Add Item</button>
        </form>
      );
    };

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    addItem: (item) => {
      dispatch(ADD_TODO_ITEM(item));
    }
  }
};

export default connect(undefined, mapDispatchToProps)(AddTodo);
```

Comment: I get 2 errors on page load 'dispatch' is not defined  no-undef and 
 'addItem' is not defined   no-undef

Comment: Can you share your code on `codepen` or `jsFiddle`? Debugging that would be easy.

Comment: From the question, I assume you're fresh to react/redux. Their are two types of components in react/redux. One is connected to redux state and other are just views which are rendered by parents. In order to dispatch action from a component, you must connect the component from redux state and describe the action which the component need to fire. In your case, it is `addToDoItem`

Comment: Also I've updated the answer. This should work. If it doesn't, please share your code on `code-pen`, I'll try to debug.